# ggplot2: Histogram, color each facet at different threshold values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a ggplot2 histogram with facet_grid. I am able to put vline at the choice of threshold for each facet. I would like to color the histogram based on that that threshold as well. So, basically bars left to the vline will have different color than to the right. Please note those thresholds are different for each facet/group.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
library("splines")
library("dplyr")
test=data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))

melt_data = melt(test,id.vars = NULL)

thresh_data = data.frame("X1" = 2, "X2" = 3, "X3" = 4, "X4" = 5)
thresh_data_melt = melt(thresh_data,id.vars = NULL)

ggplot(melt_data,aes(x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_histogram() + geom_vline(data=thresh_data_melt, aes(xintercept=value, color="red"),
                                linetype="dashed")
```

With the above code, I get the following image
[image]

Help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach merging data and computing a variable for color based on threshold. I did slight changes to your code. You could adjust the condition for computing `color` after joining the melted datasets (I used `value<=threshold` but you change that):

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("dplyr")
#Data
test=data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))

melt_data = melt(test,id.vars = NULL)

thresh_data = data.frame("X1" = 2, "X2" = 3, "X3" = 4, "X4" = 5)
thresh_data_melt = melt(thresh_data,id.vars = NULL)
names(thresh_data_melt)[2] <- 'threshold'

#Merge for color
dfjoined <- merge(melt_data,thresh_data_melt,by='variable',all.x=T)
dfjoined$color <- ifelse(dfjoined$value<=dfjoined$threshold,'before','after')
#Plot
ggplot(dfjoined,aes(x = value,fill=color)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_histogram() + geom_vline(data=thresh_data_melt, aes(xintercept=threshold, color="red"),
                                linetype="dashed",show.legend = F)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Merge is definitely a good idea. I tried using group_by -> mutate on melt_data to get the labels based on thresholds but could not find how to do it with dplyr.

Comment: @user3733314 After you merged the two melted data you could only use smth like `mutate(Label=ifelse(value<=threshold,'before','after'))` and if needed the `group_by()` you should use `variable` like `group_by(variable)`

Comment: After merging it is possible. Before merging with group_by you cannot change a variable (threshold in this case)  for each group using dplyr. Like check whats the group now after `group_by()` (say "X1" or "X2") and then pass the variables accordingly